# Insert hyperlink - browse the web button, goes grey when pressed

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I have a user whos Outlook > Insert Hyperlink > Browse the web - button, goes grey when its pressed and does not open a browser. We recently upgraded people from IE to Edge, and I thought it might be the default choice:

[Default programs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRaRZ.png)

But no matter what its changed to, it still goes grey when pressed and nothing happens.

Any clues would be helpful,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based my test in my environment with the default browser "Edge", the "Browse the web" button is available. What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

On the other hand, considering that it would also be affected when the Outlook program itself is damaged, it is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I will get this checked and report back.